# Using alias of a query to join with another table MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables.

support_works = contain serial_number 
kickscooters  = contian serial_number, kickscooter_id(as primary id, and named id) 
rents = contain kickscooter_id.

I am trying to get serial_number of support_works that satisfy conditions then match it with kickscooter's serial_number. Then get its kickscooter_id to get all rents that match kickscooter_id retrieved from it.

Currently:

```
select k.id
     from support_works sw
     join kickscooters k
       on k.serial_number = sw.serial_number
     where
       sw.work_type = 'deploy' and
       (sw.updated_at between '2019-11-01 02:00:00' and '2019-11-01 10:00:00') and 
       k.id in (select kcu.kickscooter_id
                from kickscooter_control_units kcu
                where kcu.particle_product_id in (9358, 9383)));
```

this works perfectly on getting kickscooter_id from kickscooter table. But I am now using this as subquery to get all rents table data where rents.kickscooter_id is in this subquery:

```
select *
from rents r
where r.kickscooter_id
  in (select k.id
     from support_works sw
     join kickscooters k
       on k.serial_number = sw.serial_number
     where
       sw.work_type = 'deploy' and
       (sw.updated_at between '2019-11-01 02:00:00' and '2019-11-01 10:00:00') and 
       k.id in (select kcu.kickscooter_id
                from kickscooter_control_units kcu
                where kcu.particle_product_id in (9358, 9383)));
```

This is taking too long and I want to use multiple joins to make things faster. How can I go about it?

I have been using CTE however I've read that it takes up memory while creating/deleting temporary table therefore tried to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join `kickscooter_control_units`  on your `subquery` the use `exists` keyword rather than IN.

```
select *
from rents r
where 
  exists 
  (select 1
     from support_works sw
     join kickscooters k on k.serial_number = sw.serial_number
     join kickscooter_control_units kcu on  kcu.kickscooter_id =  k.id and kcu.particle_product_id in (9358, 9383)   
     where
       sw.work_type = 'deploy' and
       (sw.updated_at between '2019-11-01 02:00:00' and '2019-11-01 10:00:00'))
```

Seems based on your scenario you are filtering the `ID`. `exists` only applicable if you want to check if certain `subquery` contains values.

```
 select *
    from rents r
    where 
      r.kickscooter_id in 
      (select k.id
         from support_works sw
         join kickscooters k on k.serial_number = sw.serial_number
         join kickscooter_control_units kcu on  kcu.kickscooter_id =  k.id and kcu.particle_product_id in (9358, 9383)   
         where
           sw.work_type = 'deploy' and
           (sw.updated_at between '2019-11-01 02:00:00' and '2019-11-01 10:00:00'))
```

Comment: kcu.particle_product_id in (9358, 9383) correctly filters? you can do that in join clause?

Comment: could you tell me what select 1 is doing? when I run just that part it all returns 1.

Comment: using exists keyword doesn't care on your columns, as long there's results.

Comment: so having 1 instead of result is more efficient? what is the reason for it.

Comment: its more faster

Comment: I see. Thanks for this. I will accept it as soon as it passes 3 mins.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202175/discussion-between-lmbloo-and-).

Comment: Hey, I don't think it filters correctly inside join.

Comment: put this one `and kcu.particle_product_id in (9358, 9383)  ` after `where`

Comment: hm...? It works by select k.id instead of 1 however then it takes a while...

Comment: still doesn't work after kcu.particle_product_id in (9358, 9383) has been placed after while