# Optimize where clause query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, pymysql

[Using alias of a query to join with another table MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58810707/using-alias-of-a-query-to-join-with-another-table-mysql/58810733?noredirect=1#comment103902574_58810733)

Similar to my previous question, it does not work with giving value of 1 from the result of subquery. Therefore I've changed it into

```
select *
from rents r
where
  r.kickscooter_id in
   (select k.id 
    from support_works sw
    join kickscooters k 
      on k.serial_number = sw.serial_number
    join kickscooter_control_units kcu 
      on  kcu.kickscooter_id =  k.id 
        and kcu.particle_product_id in (9358, 9383)   
    where
      sw.work_type = 'deploy' and
      (sw.updated_at between '2019-11-01 02:00:00' and '2019-11-01 10:00:00'));
```

but now since it needs to check every r.kickscooter_id, whether it belongs in result list of subquery it is taking too long.

How can I optimize this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using Join over Sub-query -

```
select r.*
from rents r
join kickscooters k on k.id = r.kickscooter_id
join support_works sw on k.serial_number = sw.serial_number
join kickscooter_control_units kcu on  kcu.kickscooter_id =  k.id
where kcu.particle_product_id in (9358, 9383)
and sw.work_type = 'deploy'
and sw.updated_at between '2019-11-01 02:00:00' and '2019-11-01 10:00:00'
```

Later you can create index on below fields to see the differences.

```
rents(kickscooter_id)
kickscooters(serial_number)
support_works(serial_number, work_type,updated_at)
kickscooter_control_units(kickscooter_id, particle_product_id)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to avoid CTE since I've read that it takes up memory while creating and deleting it. so joining over sub-query would be more efficient?